# How can I communicate with VLF ground waves

Tags: vlf

I willing to try really hard on working with Very Low Frequency waves to get a signal through the earth a few Km.

How can I go about putting a signal at the frequency (probably near 10 kilohertz) into the ground?

I have been searching for schematics everywhere, but just nothing shows up.

I know it is possible, I have seen some amateur radio really low frequency contacts through the earth.

I know it is slow-speed CW, but that is still worth the joy of experimenting.

Can I use ground rods instead of a HUGE antenna?

Comment: This shows very little research effort. What exactly are you asking, beyond "please design an ELF/LF transmitter for me with these parts I have"?

Comment: ELF as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremely_low_frequency is 3-30 Hz, you're talking about VLF which as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_low_frequency is 3-30 KHz.

Comment: Transmitting; Match an Audio Amplifier output impedance to the Ground rods. Receiving; Match the Audio Amplifier input impedance to the Ground rods. Space the rods a good distance apart.

Answer (score 3):

The point of a huge antenna is efficiency. Ground rods alone will result in a very small signal being received, and high transmitter mismatch. VLF antennas are massive and require both very large grounding radials as well as antennas.

The [links from the VLF page at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_low_frequency#External_links), especially the [Long Wave Radio Club of America](http://www.lwca.org) and [K4NYW's page on vintage Navy radio gear](http://www.virhistory.com/navy/xmtr-vlf.htm) has some schematics. If you can find a schematic for an [AN/FRT-96](http://www.armyproperty.com/product/80058/AN-FRT-96/) which was [still in use by the USN as of two years ago](https://www.usajobs.gov/GetJob/PrintPreview/323811000), you'll be in business. Perhaps a search on LinkedIn for [folks who list that in their skill set](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3alinkedin.com%20AN/FRT-96&t=lm) might help.